# JSON Map collection to ArrayList

Tags: java, json, resttemplate

Need help with the following case - with RestTemplate I get a response from internal server via:

```
Map<String, String> response = RestTemplate.getForObject(url, Map.class);
```

structure of the response is:

```
"mainRate" -> 2.99000  // double
"secondaryRates" -> [{rateName -> r1, rateVal -> 5.9}] //ArrayList of LinkedHashMap<String, Double>
```

First question - I cannot read from map result in a plain way as:

```
double mainRate = response.get("mainRate")
```

This would give ClassCastException. Have no idea why? Anybody had such case? Instead, I do:

```
double mainRate = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(response.get("mainRate")));
```

Kindly advise why simple way of response.get(keyName) doesn't work? It works only with conversions to String and then to double.

Second issue is with collection - how to parse nested collection of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some investigation I tried using @JSONProperty annotation on the fields of my end object and it all worked.

This is, however, not clear to my why it wasn't possible retrieving values without it

Answer (score 0):

So to the first issue:

You get a map of `Map<String, String>` so every value (and every key) of this Map is stored as a String. That's why you've got a `ClassCastException`, because the value of `mainRate` is a `String` and must be parsed with `Double.parseDouble`. (btw. I think you can leave out the `String.valueOf()` because the result of `respone.get(...)` is already a `String`).

To the second issue:
This is also possible, but I would advise you to try it another way:

You can define a class which matches the response typ.
In this case this class could look like this:

```java
public class JsonResponse {
    public double mainRate;
    public List<Map<String, Double>> secondaryRates; // Or also define a object for this

}
```

and then you could parse to this class like

```java
JsonResponse response = RestTemplate.getForObject(url, JsonResponse.class);
double mainRate = response.mainRate;
// or other stuff
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly the collection is inside the main object and if I do RestTemplate.getForObject(url, Response.class) I get a response object with all nulls

Comment: Okay I overlooked that it is a collection and corrected my answer. But normally that shouldn't give a object with all nulls. It is important that the field names matches the key of the JSON, so it is important that the variable is called `mainRate` and not `mainrate` or something else. 
But if that really doesn't work you can have a look at this: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template, here is explained how to parse it with an actual JSON parser (`Jackson`)